# MDP implementation using python - dimensions

Tags: python, transition, reward, mdp

I have problem in implementing `mdp` (markov decision process) by python.

I have these matrices: `states: (1 x n)` and `actions: (1 x m)`
.Transition matrix is calculated by this code:

```
p = np.zeros((n,n))
for t in range(l): # my data is a 1x100 matrix
p[states[t]-1, states[t+1]-1] = p[states[t]-1, states[t+1]-1] + 1
for i in range(n):
p[i,:] = p[i, :] / np.sum(p[i, :])
```

and Reward matrix by this code:

```
for i in range(l): 
Reward = (states[i+1]-states[i])/(states[i])*100
```

To have the optimal value, "quantecon package" in python is defined by:

```
ddp = quantecon.markov.DiscreteDP(R, Q, beta)
```

where Q : transition matrix should be `m x n x m`.

Can anyone help me understand how Q can be a (m,n,m) matirx?!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `n` states and `m` actions, `Q` will be an array of shape `(n, m, n)` (not `(m, n, m)`), where you let `Q[s, a, t]` store the probability that the state in the next period becomes the `t`-th state when the current state is the `s`-th state and the action taken is the `a`-th action.